# Purpose of super() when class does not inherit

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

I have found a code in realpython.com about python super() and I don't understand what is the purpose of the super() in Rectangle and Triangle **init** method if both classes have no parent (don't inherit).

```
    class Rectangle:
        def __init__(self, length, width, **kwargs):
            self.length = length
            self.width = width
            super().__init__(**kwargs)

        def area(self):
            return self.length * self.width

    class Square(Rectangle):
        def __init__(self, length, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(length=length, width=length, **kwargs)

    class Triangle:
        def __init__(self, base, height, **kwargs):
            self.base = base
            self.height = height
            super().__init__(**kwargs)

        def tri_area(self):
            return 0.5 * self.base * self.height

    class RightPyramid(Square, Triangle):
        ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way, these classes can work with multiple-inheritance, and they *may* get ancestors unknown at coding time - the call to `super`, passing any unknown parameters they may have got, ensures they will play nice when used this way.

For example, let's suppose these shapes are used to represent the creation concrete 3D printing plastic objects.

```
class Print3D:
    def __init__(self, *, filament="PLA", **kw):
         self.filament=filament 
         print("Print3D part initialized")
         super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

One now can do:

```
class PrintedSquare(Square, Print3D):
    pass

mysquare = PrintedSquare(length=20, filament="PVC")
```

and everything will just work.